# Collection references in Model in Entity Framework (.NET MVC C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Basically, when I pass a model from the controller and into my view, the collections are null. The way I fixed this was to get this collection from the database and just manually set it in my model before passing it to the view. However, this collection contains an object of my original model, and this model in the collection contains a new collection, and this one is NOT null.

Model 1:

```
public class Trip : DbContext
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public float StartLat { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public float StartLon { get; set; }
    public float EndLat { get; set; }
    public float EndLon { get; set; }
    public float Distance { get; set; }

    public ICollection<TripRecord> TripRecords { get; set; }
    public ICollection<TollRecord> TollRecords { get; set; }
}
```

Model 2:

```
public class TripRecord : DbContext
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Trip Trip { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public float Lat { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public float Lon { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime DeviceTime { get; set; }
}
```

My controller:

```
public ActionResult EditTrip(int id)
    {
        var trip = trackerContext.Trips
                .Where(t => t.ID == id)
                .FirstOrDefault();

        //Manually set TripRecords
        var records = trackerContext.TripRecords
            .Where(c => c.Trip.ID == id)
            .ToList();
        trip.TripRecords = records;

        return View(trip);
    }
```

If I remove the code bellow the comment, Trip.TripRecords will be null. However, if I let it stay and try to access Model.TripRecords.First().Trip.TripRecords.Count, I will get 4. Why is this?? As far as I know, the Trip in the TripRecords does not use my "fix"..

Comment: Make you collections virtual so they are lazy loaded by EF -  `public virtual ICollection<TripRecord> TripRecords { get; set; }` (or you can use `.Include()`)

Comment: How would this include look like for me?? And how can I "exclude" the reference back to Trip from TripRecord?? Its throwing exceptions when I try to Json Encode :(

Comment: `var trip = trackerContext.Trips.Where(t => t.ID == id).Include(t => t.TripRecords).FirstOrDefault();`. Suggest your read [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/data/jj574232.aspx)

Comment: I was missing this reference "using System.Data.Entity;" for the Include to work, I actually had it right :) Thanks for the article, Ill check it out!

Comment: Which version of entityframework u are using?

Comment: does Stephen's comment solves your issue?

Comment: It was helpful, as it shortens my code a little bit. But I still dont understand why my Trip models are different, why one of them contains foreign key table by default and the other doesnt.